# Problem search with IIS UrlRewrite

Tags: search

Excuse me for my english but my first language is french

I have http web application http://mycompany.fr with site collection http://mycompany.fr in SharePoint entreprise 2013 (one server sharepoint et one server sql)

AAM
Internal URL               Zone             Public URL for Zone
http://mycompany.fr        Default          http://mycompany.fr

I am add https
certificat in IIS (mycompany.fr), AAM  and content source search modify

Internal URL                     Zone                 Public URL for Zone
http://mycompany.fr              Default              http://mycompany.fr
https://mycompany.fr             Personal             https://mycompany.fr

content source search
http://mycompany.fr
https://mycompany.fr

for the users
http, https and Search Service Application works

now, I would like to redirecting the user from http to https to enforce SSL communication
i am use IIS URL Rewrite module

web.config webapp http://mycompany.fr

[image]

for the users
URL https://mycompany.fr works
URL http://mycompany.fr is well transformed in https://mycompany.fr

My problem is that the search does not work.
New documents are not indexed however the two site are well accessible on the server
In the Analysis Log for the Search Service Application for the two URL https://mycompany.fr and http://mycompany.fr
An unrecognized HTTP response was received when attempting to crawl this item and Access denied errors.

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell from your question, but you should always crawl the default zone. Do not put in start addresses from other zones.

If you do your AAM correctly, you do not need the URL rewrite redirection. SharePoint does not work well that way. (I am actually surprised you got it to work.) You can add new Public Addresses and SharePoint will handle the redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried other redirect methods - "Permanently Moved" or "Found"?

I suggest:

- Make HTTPS the default zone, since that is what you want everyone to be using
- Set crawler to crawl HTTPS version, since it is the default zone
- Use IIS to redirect HTTP to HTTPS, to catch all external links and bookmarks etc - as far as I remember, SharePoint does not redirect from HTTP to HTTPS itself, that's up to IIS.
- Keep HTTP version as an AAM, this will make SharePoint APIs understand HTTP and HTTPS are the same thing
- Use "Permanently moved" redirect to permanently redirect (browsers will stop trying to connect to http version = better performance but will not be possible to cancel the redirection), OR Found redirection (browser will ask server each time)

Comment: Hello,

Make HTTPS the default zone : i have error "acces denied" with account service !!!

I am recreated my web application in https, and use URL rewrite and its works

Thanks you

Comment: Which service account is getting access denied? Crawl account needs to have Full read on web application policy